# Laravel 5, how to send API token to mobile app

Tags: api, rest, authentication, laravel-5

I have a mobile app which will call a REST API written using Laravel(5.2) framework.

This article on [Laravel API authentication](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51) mentions how to authenticate users making calls to such an API. The caller should send the correct `api_token` to the server in the request.

My question is what would be a good way to get the api token to the mobile app? I'm currently thinking of creating a rest api which will authenticate the user based on `username` and `password` sent in the request and send the `api_token` in the response if the user sends a valid username/password pair. Is this method correct/secure? What things should I consider additionally if I do use this method?

Answer (score 2):

You must use one of this methods to have a secure API

- JWT TOKEN https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth
- OAUTH2 https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

With this methods you only send once username and password and you obtain a token that is valid for a time you can decide. But as bigger is the time, more insecure.

To solve this, there are a renew token methods. With a valid token, you can obtain another valid and refresh the old. In this way, the username and password are more protected because they are  not sent in every request.

Is not a good idea have the same token for each user all the time, as you saw in the example you provide. It´s very insecure. If someone get this token, he always  will can send request in your name. The tokens must have a lifetime.

to answer your question how to send API token to mobile app i will recommend you that your mobile apps get a valid token and after refresh it.
Something as this works great to get a token in your app:

```
if ( thereAreTokenStored() )
{
    if (! theTokenStoredIsValid() )
    {
        $authentication = refreshToken();
    }
}
else
{
    $authentication = authenticate();
}
```

To know all this issues I recommend you this book: https://apisyouwonthate.com/ . I learnt a lot of the 'API WORLD' with this book. It will help you to know all you need to create an API in a professional way and will provide the necessary tools and packages to achieve it and save a lot of work. And you will love your API!!

Comment: Actually, I switched de OAUTH2 to JWT because works better with Laravel 5.2. and doesn't need a database. More easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this approach is safe. Additionally you also need to secure your connection to server by using HTTPS with a SSL certificate.